# Kibana helm install error with MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "elasticsearch-certs" : secret "elasticsearch-master-certs" not found

Tags: kubernetes, kibana, kubernetes-helm

I am not able to install Kibana with simple helm command which used to work earlier.

"helm install kibana elastic/kibana -n kibana"

Are there any recent changes in kibana helm? Do we need to create elasticseach-master-certs and elasticsearch-credentials secrets prior to kibana install now.

https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/elastic/kibana

Answer (score 1):

As per the latest release notes, For Kibana 8.XX version they have enabled authentication and TLS by default. For me I already had elasticsearch installed which is serving on http port so we have to enable TLS in elasticsearch first. As the Kibana-elasticseach communication must be tls enabled as per latest kibana release.

For testing purpose(we are not working on Production anyways ) we are okay with accessing kibana using port-forward too so i have installed 7.XX version helm chart and moved ahead.

https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/7.17/kibana/README.md

If you want to enable tls for ES, kibana i found below link helpful.

https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/main/kibana/examples/security (this example is from kibana GIT repo itself)

https://www.lisenet.com/2022/deploy-elasticsearch-and-kibana-on-kubernetes-with-helm/

https://thomasdecaux.medium.com/setup-https-tls-for-kibana-with-helm-cert-manager-io-fd1a326085fe